# Can you unzip a .zip on a remote server?

Tags: php, ftp, zip

I have a script unzips files on the server but is it possible to unzip files on an external or remote server.

For instance can I go

```
<?php 
$zip = new ZipArchive; 
$zip->open('ftp://user:password@host/path/file.zip'); 
$zip->extractTo('ftp://user:password@host/'); 
$zip->close(); 
echo "Ok!"; ?>
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Copy the file to your server (programmatically), then unzip it.

Comment: I was hoping to dynamically build a script that transfer files from one server to another and extracts it.

Comment: Yes, so add one line of code before yours to copy the file to your server before you extract it. `file_put_contents('file.zip', file_get_contents('ftp://user:password@host/path/file.zip'));` then `$zip->open('file.zip');`

Comment: Do you have the ZZIPlib module installed for Apache?

Comment: Ok so above is only a snippet but the rest of the php file has a class that connects to FTP -> uploads the file and then the zip snipper extracts the uploaded file but I can't seem to figure out a way to extract the file on the external server.

Comment: That's not what you said or what your code implied. Look at sbrichards' answer.

Comment: @Dan Grossman woudn't that upload the file to the external server then transfer the file back to the original server and extract it?

Comment: The question says unzip a file ON a remote server not From a remote server.

Comment: @DanGrossman: That would work ( `file_put_contents( ... file_get_contents( .. ) )` ), but could also result in collisions if more than one download/unzip is in progress simultaneously.

Comment: @user827570 I have edited your question so that the code example reflects what you meant to ask. Asking if you can `extractTo('./')` implies you want to extract to the server the code is on, not the remote server. What the "on a remote server" refers to (the file, or where to extract it) alone was ambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

to unzip a remote file on a server with PHP a rather simple solution that worked for me is:

1. ftp the zip file, say `a.zip`, to the remote folder where you want it extracted
2. create a php file `unzip.php` and ftp it to the same folder as the zip file above
3. insert the following code into `unzip.php`:

```php
<?php 
  $zip = new ZipArchive; 
  $zip->open('a.zip');
  $zip->extractTo('x/'); 
  $zip->close(); 
  echo "Ok!"; 
?>
```

1. set chmod of `unzip.php` to executable
2. execute the php file from any browser - you shd get an 'Ok' confirming the extraction

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following via an ssh connection to that server:

```
<?php
$connection = ssh2_connect('example.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'unzip /path/to/file.zip');
?>
```

More info here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-exec.php

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response but I'm have an issue running the above code I receive  "Call to undefined function ssh2_connect() on line 2"

Comment: You need to compile PHP with SSH support.

Comment: I'm not extremely familiar with PHP, but I reccomend reading http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-exec.php and make sure you have ssh set up on your server and verify port/username/password

Comment: You don't need to recompile PHP, just install the ssh2 package from PECL.